# Index in Vertica creation

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to create an index but I've an error:

> ```
> SQL Error [2676] [0A000]:
> [Vertica][VJDBC](2676) ERROR: Command CREATE INDEX is not supported   
> [Vertica][VJDBC](2676) ERROR: Command CREATE INDEX is not supported
> [Vertica][VJDBC](2676) ERROR: Command CREATE INDEX is not supported
> ```

Is it possible to create an index in Vertica (version 7)?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name_table_lookup ON name_table (field 1, field 2);
```

Comment: Vertica does not use indexes; rather a concept called projections. What is the reason you're trying to create indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to learn more about how Vertica works.  Specifically, I would read the [concepts guide](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Other/TheHPVerticaApproach.htm%3FTocPath%3DConcepts%2520Guide|_____1).  Be sure to read through many of the sections in the navigator on the left side.

The short answer is, there are no indexes in Vertica.  Instead, there are projections, which are copies of data that are sorted, segmented and encoded to optimally execute your queries.

You may not even need to create additional projections. I would not assume (especially as someone new to Vertica) that you need to create projections that match indexes you might have had in other DBMS.

I would create the table, populate it with a representative set of data, write some queries that you plan to use often... then run the Database Designer tool that comes with Vertica in Comprehensive mode (subsequently you can do incremental designs if you add new query patterns or change how you use the table). I actually tend to do a few more steps here, but if you are just starting, keep it simple.

So, things to read up on (all in the concepts guide mentioned above), in no particular order:

1. Projections
2. Database Designer
3. Column Stores vs Row Stores
4. Logical Vs Physical Schemas

And very likely you will want to read about how to load data, which is also in the concepts guide.

Good luck!

Comment: @sowe Before or after this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible ! No indexes allowed in Vertica ! This would make Vertica slower.

Why would you use an index ?

Maybe you need a primary key or a specific projection.

**Primary Key**

```
alter table test add primary key (col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

projection basically is like cluster index , it will do the same jobs as regular indexes .

In general ,  Vertica is targeting for different use case than for example oracle database or mysql. its more suitable for massive sequential read and less for small seek index base access .

Vertica Use case is more targeting for reporting and DWH use cases  so regulare b-tree indexes are less relevant

Thanks